# Best practice for updating list on website

Tags: c#, html, ajax, list, model-view-controller

I've created an ASP.NET MVC application. We have a list which shows all items currently in a database. We also have a button, which shows a popup-dialog where you can create another entry. We want to add this item to the list when it is created. Now my question is, which of the following method is better for this:

- Adding the item manually (via javascript) into the list. My concern is, that it feels quiet hacky/not very good practice.
- Reloading the page, so all entries are reloaded from the database.

Which of the methods is better for this purpose in terms of performance and "good practice" (I should mention that the list will likley hover around the 100-200 items mark)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: there's nothing wrong with asynchronously loading data into the page - it's what most sites do, including here. Also, too often the term "best practice" is used as a way to avoid having to think - instead look for the solution that best suits your need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a callback to the server, and on success of that callback then you can go on and add that new item in the list. No need to refresh the whole page.

Something like this (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6133699/125740)):

```
$.ajax({ url: '/Controller/Action/Id',
     success: function(data) { alert(data); }, 
     statusCode : {
         404: function(content) { alert('cannot find resource'); },
         500: function(content) { alert('internal server error'); }
     }, 
     error: function(req, status, errorObj) {
           // handle status === "timeout"
           // handle other errors
     }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I would re-load the list asynchronously.  Depending on how it is coded, this can either be done via server side code or via a javascript ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by being able to submit the form and reload the page.

The you could add the ability to submit the form using ajax, then if the form passes and validation and returns a success message, add the new item to the list via javascript.

This way, if someone disables javascript, they can still submit the form, but they just get a page refresh. Or if the ajax call fails you can still resort to a page refresh.

Comment: if they have disabled javascript then they don't deserve to be on the 21st century internet.

Comment: Disabling javascript can have a few benefits. Such as no adverts, not analytics tracking your every move, improved security, faster sites as not running / processing javascript.

Comment: blanket banning javascript will also break most websites functionality. I know there are tools like NoScript which are designed for the security-conscious, but javascript has become a fundamental part of the modern internet and is not something to just be gotten rid of.