# Why i can not call the controller from ajax in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm beginner in `asp.net mvc` ,i want to call the controller action from Ajax code ,for that purpose read this tutorial:
[CALL CONTROLLER WITH AJAX](http://www.makeitspendit.com/calling-asp-mvc-controllers-from-jquery-ajax/)

write this action method in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void Test01()
        {
            string behzad = "BEHZAD RAZZAQI";

        }
```

and in view page write this html code:

```
<button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-success">ثبـت نـام</button>
```

in on that view page write this `jquery` code:

```
<script>
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/MainPage/Test01",
            datatype: "text",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');//$('#testarea').html("All OK");
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#testarea").html("ERROR");
            }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

but when i fire the button i can not see any alert,what happen?how can i solve that problem?

Comment: 1. Is 'MainPage' given in ajax url your controller name?   2. Is that javascript method hitting when you click the button? Try putting an alert before ajax call.                      3. Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: any error you seen in Browser `Console` ?

Comment: @Developer i get this message in browser console:Warning: NetUtil.asyncFetch() requires the channel to have one of the security flags set in the loadinfo (see nsILoadInfo). Please create channel using NetUtil.newChannel()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url:'<%= Url.Action("Test01", "MainPage") %>',
            success: function(data) {
                 alert("ok");
            }
        });
    });

 });
```

Make sure that **MainPage** is the name of your controller and that you included your jquery library, just like @bhupesh stated:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-*.*.*.min.js"></script>
```

Further information can be found [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119098/how-to-call-controller-actions-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: i want that ajax run when the button fire,How can change that code?

Comment: Just put that code inside your button click funcion.

Comment: i write simle test function into script tag,and write onclick="test()" into the button click ,into test function write alert('ok') and when button fire that show,but when your ajax file copy into test function and fire the button,alert not show me

Comment: thanks my friend,write simple alert into the $("#btn1").click(function () { function,out of ajax,and dont show that!

Comment: mmm... It migth be due to your document is not ready or might be due to you are not including your jquery library properly... please, see your page source code and make sure you are referencing the jquery library properly.. anyway I updated the answer for executing the code just after your document is ready..

Answer (score 0):

please make sure you have included jquery script file in your page.

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-*.*.*.min.js"></script>
```