# How to pass the object in $.ajax

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax

Hi all following is my object

```
 $scope.myObject= {
    ID: { "value": "", "column": "ID" },
    Name: { "value": "", "column": "Name" },
    Desc: { "value": "", "column": "Desc" },
    IsActive: { "value": "", "column": "IsActive" },
    CreatedBy: { "value": "", "column": "CreatedBy" },
    ModifiedBy: { "value": "", "column": "ModifiedBy" },
    CreatedDate: { "value": "", "column": "CreatedDate" },
    ModifiedDate: { "value": "", "column": "ModifiedDate" },
    ConGp: { "value": "", "column": "ConGp" },
    SortIndex: { "value": "", "column": "SortIndex" },
    PageNumber: { "value":"", "column": "PageNumber" },
    PageSize: { "value": "", "column": "PageSize" }
}
```

value will get fill from html text box
I want to pass this object in ajax call

```
  $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "GET",
                    data: JSON.stringify($scope.myObject),
                     success: function (data) {

                        $scope.FRP= data.RM;
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
```

But on MVC Controller side data always get null value but while sending the object $scope.myObject the value is filled it is getting lost in ajax call. Please Suggest.

Comment: It's rather odd that you'd even want to send an object tied to Angular through jQuery...? [Try this instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131659/from-jquery-ajax-to-angular-http).

Comment: 1. you are using angularjs so replace `$.ajax` with `$http`. 2. you need a POST request, so use `$http.post` instead. E.g. `$http.post(url,$scope.myObject).then((res) => {$scope.FRP = res.data.RM; ...})`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: even though I replace the $.ajax with $http my object value getting lost in the $http call.

Comment: Could you add some web service code?

Comment: `lost` not sure what do you mean by that . can you check your request body in network dev tools .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119098/how-to-call-controller-actions-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: What it the signature of your MVC controller function?

Comment: public ActionResult GetAssociateUser(MyObject myObject)

Comment: can you log the whole request and append that to your question please?@RiteshGore

Comment: could it possible be that your ajax call needs `data: { myObject : JSON.stringify($scope.myObject) }` ? i.e. the stringified object named as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send data, use "POST" method. Either $.ajax or $http.post

Answer (score 0):

For sending data to DB/server we need to use the post request.
If you are using MVC framework i would like to suggest you to use `[axios][1]`.
Which is a `Promise based HTTP client for the browser`.

For your question :-

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify($scope.myObject),
  success: function(data) {
    $scope.FRP = data.RM;
    $scope.$apply();
  }
});
```