# Direct delete link from index view instead of going to delete page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a link that will delete one of the records without the need to go to the delete page.

My controller for delete section:

```
 // GET: Cars/Delete/5
    public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(Guid? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Car car = await db.Cars.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (car == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(car);
    }

    // POST: Cars/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
    {
        Car car = await db.Cars.FindAsync(id);
        db.Cars.Remove(car);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

In the view I am trying to have a link to directly delete it like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DeleteConfirmed", "Cars", new { id=item.Id })" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick = "return confirm('Are sure wants to delete?');">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

The most common solution to do it is by creating a form and do it like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteConfirmed", "Cars", new { id = item.Id }))
 {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <input type="submit" value="&#xf00d;" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Are sure wants to delete?');" />
 }
```

Is there is a way to make it without the need of using the form?

Comment: A Delete action is altering data, so it should always be a `[HttpPost]` (or `[HttpDelete]`) method, therefore you should be using a form, not a link (which makes a GET). Why do you not want a form?

Comment: What you want to achieve is making an asynchronous request from the client.
You can bind a javascript function that asynchronously calls your Delete action method to a button click in your view. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119098/how-to-call-controller-actions-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc) for examples on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Please refer to the code below:

> input type="button" id="btnDelete" class="btn btn-danger"
>   value="Delete" />

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnDelete").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Cars/Delete",
            type: 'POST',
            data: { id='-your-id' },
            async: 'true',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                //Do your thing on Success if needed
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```