# Get value from Controller using JQuery AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want to get new value from `controller` and set it to `view` when form submit.

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetVoucherNo()
    {
        var voucherno = 1001;

        var lastvoucherno = db.PaymentsAndReceipts.Where(x => x.StakeHolder.StakeHolderType.Name == "Supplier").OrderBy(x => x.VoucherNo).ToList().LastOrDefault();

        if (lastvoucherno != null)
        {
            voucherno = lastvoucherno.VoucherNo.GetValueOrDefault() + 1;
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = voucherno, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

**My Jquery function:**

I just want to do when this **`function`** calls, I can get the value from **`controller action`**.

```
function getVoucherNo()
{
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: 'Payments/GetVoucherNo',
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function () {
    //don't know what to do here.
    });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Call Controller Actions using JQuery in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119098/how-to-call-controller-actions-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: you can do a `.success()` and `.fail()` before you do the done. Just for example do `.done((result) => { console.log(result); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data should be available in the `done` function argument like this:

```
function getVoucherNo()
{
   $.ajax({
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      url: 'Payments/GetVoucherNo',
      dataType: "json"
   }).done(function (result) {
     //don't know what to do here.
     console.log(result);
     //you should see the exact JSON you return from the controller
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I done it with `success`.

```
function getVoucherNo()
{
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        url: '/Payments/GetVoucherNo',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            return $('#VoucherNo').val(result); //to set value in textbox.
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr);
            console.log(xhr, status, error);
        }
    });
}
```