# ajax jquery to load a html contents

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if the code/question doesn't make sense, but if it does, hopefully someone helps give me some guidance.

In AJAX (jquery),
`$('.shift-template').html(X);`

I need to feed to 'X' with this code (dynamic contents).

```
@model ScheduleUsers.Models.ScheduledWorkPeriod

@{
    var shifttemplates = ViewData["shifttemplates"] as List<ScheduleUsers.Models.ScheduleShiftTemplate>;
}

<td id="shift-template-content">
    <select id="shift-template-@shiftcount" name="shifttemplate" class="form-control shift-template">
        @foreach (var st in shifttemplates)
        {
            @* If shift Id is (id 1), then display blank*@
            if (st.Id == "1")
            {
                <option value="@st.Id">-</option>
            }
            @* Else show shift template row*@
            else
            {
                var st_start = st.StartTime.Value.ToString("h:mm tt");
                var st_end = st.EndTime.Value.ToString("h:mm tt");
                <option value="@st_start|@st_end">@st_start - @st_end</option>
            }
        }
    </select>

</td>
```

What I try to accomplish is when the jquery success, the portion (contents) of entire page needs to auto refreshed with it instead of the entire page manual reload.

Comment: How do you render this View from the Controller action?

Comment: you mean this?
```return PartialView("_scheduleShiftsTable", scheduleVM);```

Comment: Yes.. you need to call that controller action via AJAX.

Comment: How can I do it, could you give me the reference?

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119098/how-to-call-controller-actions-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I aimed to utilize $('.shift-template').html(X); instead of get to call the url action. honestly i am not sure your suggestion valid for my original intention.

Answer (score 0):

First time for my ajax experiment and learned how ajax works.
Here is what I have succeeded.

I created a new method to feed the port of table rows from database and let the ajax call the method and update the table rows specifically.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("DropDownAction", "Schedule")",
    success: function(response) {
        $('.shift-template').html(response);
    },
    error:function(){
    alert("Error!");
    }
});
```