# asp.net core <a asp-controller="" asp-action=""/> run from jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, view

Net Core Mvc 6

I have a Menu like this

```
<li class="active nav-item h5"><a class="nav-link link-light aEmployer" asp-controller="Employer" asp-action="Index">Employer Setup</a></li>
```

That returns a View

I need to call this from Ajax.

I sow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119098/how-to-call-controller-actions-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc) and what it says to do

```
$.ajax({
    // edit to add steve's suggestion.
    //url: "/ControllerName/ActionName",
    url: '<%= Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName") %>',
    success: function(data) {
         alert(data);
    }
});
```

But in this case, it returns a PartialView.

What I need is to return a View.. the same View that is returned when the user click the Option Menu.

What I need is something like `('aa').click()` but it does not work in this case...

It is a way to call it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to call an action that returns a PartialView using ajax and then display the PartialView?

Comment: I need to return a View.... the same View that is rendered when you click... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the id attribute of your anchor element:

```
<a id="employer-setup-link" class="nav-link link-light aEmployer" asp-controller="Employer" asp-action="Index">Employer Setup</a>
```

And then you can do:

```js
document.getElementById('employer-setup-link').click();
```

You can also try:

```js
window.location.href = document.getElementById('employer-setup-link').getAttribute('href');
```

Comment: IT does not work... <a> does not have a click() event.. so when you call .click(); nothing happend

Comment: It works: https://jsfiddle.net/agnsqut8/

Comment: I added another possible solution to my answer.